# error: bad operand types for binary operator '-' while subtracting Integer and int

Tags: java

My code is as follows and causing me an error: 
`error: bad operand types for binary operator '-'`.
I am subtracting Integer and int, but I think Java converts that automatically now for us, and it should not cause any error. If I try and print the value of curr.getValue(), I get the correct Integer value. However, when I try and subtract or compare it, I get errors. Do I need to convert Integer to int and then perform operations like '+' and '-'? Shouldn't they be automatically converted from Integer to int and vice-versa?

```
class Solution {
    private String function(String s){
        HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    for(char ch: s.toCharArray()){
        Integer count = map.get(ch);
        if(count == null){
            count = 0;
        }
        map.put(ch, count += 1);
    }

    Queue<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(s.length(), (a, b) -> b.getValue() - a.getValue());

    pq.addAll(map.entrySet());


    Queue<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> q = new LinkedList<>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while(!pq.isEmpty()){
        Map.Entry curr = pq.poll();
        sb.append(curr.getKey());
        curr.setValue(   curr.getValue() - 1  ); //this causes an error.
        q.offer(curr);

        if(q.size() < 2){
            continue;
        }

        Map.Entry e = q.poll();
        if(e.getValue() > 0){
            pq.offer(e);
        }
    }

    return sb.toString().length() == s.length() ? sb.toString() : "";   
}


public String reorganizeString(String S) {
    return (function(S));


}
}
```

Please tell me what is causing this error?

Comment: Why is curr declared as the raw `Map.Entry`?

Comment: You removed the type from your inner Map.Entry.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for telling me about this. I am new to Java, and had no idea that this was causing the error. I was trying to figure out if there is some Type Conversion Error from Integer to int. Please do tell me how do I fix this? I searched online, and could find doing something like: `Entry<Character, Integer> curr`, but that gives me an error. Thanks!

Comment: `Map.Entry<Character, Integer> curr`

Comment: Thanks so much for clearing this up for me! It works!